# Problem sending a get request using sockets (PYTHON)

Tags: python, sockets

My Code:

```
import socket
request = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: api16-normal-c-useast1a.tiktokv.com\n\n"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("api16-normal-c-useast1a.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/aweme/favorite/?max_cursor=0&count=0&ac=wifi&aid=1180&user_id=6986127446509143000", 80))
s.send(request)
result = s.recv(10000)
while (len(result) > 0):
    print(result)
    result = s.recv(10000)
```

My Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    s.connect(("api16-normal-c-useast1a.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/aweme/favorite/?max_cursor=0&count=0&ac=wifi&aid=1180&user_id=6986127446509143000", 80))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Any help is appreciated thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

An argument to `connect` should only contain a domain name, with the request path provided in the request itself. You should change you code to the following:

```
import socket
request = b"GET /aweme/v1/aweme/favorite/?max_cursor=0&count=0&ac=wifi&aid=1180&user_id=6986127446509143000 HTTP/1.1\nHost: api16-normal-c-useast1a.tiktokv.com\n\n"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("api16-normal-c-useast1a.tiktokv.com", 80))
s.send(request)
result = s.recv(10000)
while (len(result) > 0):
    print(result)
    result = s.recv(10000)
```

Comment: Thank you!  worked perfectly, I have another question... do you know a way to only read the response and not the response headers and status code?

Comment: Glad to help. You cannot read only the body if you wish to use `socket`. If you need to issue HTTP requests you better use [requests library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).